# php file functions vs sql

Tags: php, sql, scalability

I'm writing several small PHP applications for a business with roughly 25 employees. I'm currently using PHP file functions to store data for daily entries in order to track worker productivity. The company I work for has offices all over the globe however, and in keeping in mind that I may need to scale these applications for thousands of workers, I'm wondering if there are significant drawbacks to using file functions vs. SQL for storing user data. I know that generally speaking SQL uses resources more efficient than php, but if I'm not storing huge amounts of data at any time or for any one individual will there be a significant difference in performance? Are there other potential issues I should be concerned about?

Comment: PHP file function means ? Are you storing data in a text file?

Comment: I've got 5 nines confidence that is what he means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely huge drawbacks to using files for your data store. All major DBMs give you search, replication in some fashion, ability to store data orthogonally, etc. All of this with you writing nothing except the table definitions and the queries. No code to manage files of information or worries about race conditions.

If you are on Windows, WampServer will give you your Apache, PHP, and MySQL ready to go. PostgreSQL can also be substituted, but that is extra work.

Comment: Alright. Sounds like it's time to learn the mysql functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using file to store the data is bad idea.

Now it will be fine for you. Because you have 25 users and 25 entries will come daily.

Think about future, may be 2 year

```
25 * 2 * 365  (25 can increase in 2 years)
```

And again, later you want to generate a report. One user performance, how will you take. How much you will code to parse the file ?

`Mysql` you will get lot of options, like daily report, monthly report, each person report etc etc with some simple queries

Answer (score 0):

it does not matter if there is 1 employee or 25 employees or 25,000 employees.. the way to go is SQL always. and in fact coding flat files will be much tougher than using sql in reality because with SQL u have the liberty to choose third party vendors for all tiers be it the data tier or the application tier or the backend tier.. A software written for 20,000 employees might not be much different from one written for 1 employee per se except the amount of hardware resources thrown in the 20,000 employees base software will be probably 100 times higher and of course there will be other features like multiple server nodes, chained event handlers and replicated database servers  to maximise resources but that layer will be sitting on top of the software already written and will impact ur software coding to a very less extent, yeah i agree the architecture does change but there are ways in modern systems to make an architecturally flawed design into a sufficient one by throwing in hardware resources to counter the flaw.. just a thought really ..